# How do I check and indicate that a product is already in the cart?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to show the complete products list, but indicate which products are already in the cart? What's the conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This StackExchange question explains how to set an array of IDs for items in your cart, and then compare those IDs against the IDs of a list of products: [Check if cart contains valid products for discount code](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/check-if-cart-contains-valid-products-for-discount-code)